# Calling the exported modules in nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

For example:
we import express module

```
var express = require("express");
```

Then as per my understanding, if we type express(), then this means that there is a function in express module where this function is declined with no input parameters like function init (){code....}

```
var app = express();
```

And it's the only exported function from that module (express in our case), like the following:

```
module.exports = init
```

Then again as per my understanding, if we were able to run express() without any error then we cannot run the following:

```
express.JSON()
```

or calling any other function

My clarifications: what is happening when we call express() vs express.function(), and what is module.export is looking in express module

Answer (score 0):

Functions are objects. They can do anything an object can do.

```js
function foo() {
  console.log("Foo!");
}

foo.bar = function bar() {
  console.log("Bar!");
}

foo();
foo.bar();
```

… and a module can export any kind of value. Object. Function. String. Whatever.

Comment: Loot to ops.js module:
**
console.log("I'm in ops module")
function info() {
    console.log("I'm in info function")
}
function area(x, y) {
    console.log("I'm in area function")
    return x * y
}
function circumference(x, y) {
    console.log("I'm in circumference function")
    return 2 * x + 2 * y
}
// module.exports = info
module.exports = {
    info: info,
    area: area,
    circumference: circumference
}**

And  app.js with the following code:
**var app1 = require("./ops.js")
app1()**

app1() will produce error, then why express() is not ?

Comment: @MohammadMilhem The value ops.js exports isn’t a function. The value express exports is a function. All functions are objects but the reverse isn’t true.